# Dynamic concerns with inheritance not loading twice, but only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, separation-of-concerns, activesupport-concern

We are loading code dynamically with concerns, based on some environment variables, which works pretty nice.

Something like this:

```
# User class
class User
  include DynamicConcern
end
```

```
module DynamicConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    if "Custom::#{ENV["CUSTOMER_NAME"].camelize}::#{self.name}Concern".safe_constantize
      include "Custom::#{ENV["CUSTOMER_NAME"].camelize}::#{self.name}Concern".constantize 
    end
  end
end
```

```
# custom code
module Custom::Custom123::UserConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  
  included do
    ...
  end
end
```

We are using this since years and it worked absolutely fine in models. Some days ago we tried to use the same approach with Controllers, but realized that this approach doesn'
t work fine with inheritance, where the parent class inherits the concern as well as the inherited class:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # this gets loaded and includes the right dynamic module
  include DynamicConcern 
end

class ShopController < ApplicationController
  # this is NOT getting loaded again and skipped, 
  # since it has been loaded already in the parent controller
  include DynamicConcern 
end
```

Is there a way to tell rails that it should include/evaluade the concern a second time, since the second time it would have another class name which would include another module?

I'm not looking for other solutions, since a lot of our code is based on this approach and I think it's possible to solve this without rewriting everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's a feature of Rails that the same module doesn't get loaded multiple times.

We started to use the normal ruby module inclution hooks and it worked fine!

```
module CustomConcern

  def self.included(base)
    custom_class_lookup_paths = [
      "#{HOSTNAME.camelize}::Models::#{base.name}PrependConcern",
      "#{HOSTNAME.camelize}::Controllers::#{base.name}PrependConcern"
    ].map{|class_string| class_string.safe_constantize }.compact

    custom_class_lookup_paths.each do |class_string|
      base.send :include, class_string
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only trying to dynamically include modules based on the class name.

It's not necessary to make a concern but it can be a normal class, and the include action can be a normal method. Every time you want to call it, just call it like any other method.

Because you have already written your code with `ActiveSupport::Concern` in an `include` fashion. I guess the following refactor may work even though I cannot guarantee it. The idea is simple:

1. Just make it a normal method with the target class as the parameter. You can include it (it automatically calls `dynamic_include` in `included` hook).
2. If the module is already included in the ancestor hierarchy chain, just invoke the `dynamic_include` will immediately call the method and do the dynamic includes.

Please give it a try and let me know if it works for your scenarios.

```rb
module DynamicConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.dynamic_include(klass)
      if "Custom::#{ENV["CUSTOMER_NAME"].camelize}::#{klass.name}Concern".safe_constantize
        klass.include "Custom::#{ENV["CUSTOMER_NAME"].camelize}::#{klass.name}Concern".constantize 
      end
    end
    dynamic_include(self)
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # this gets loaded and includes the right dynamic module
  include DynamicConcern 
end

class ShopController < ApplicationController
  # this is NOT getting loaded again and skipped, 
  # since it has been loaded already in the parent controller
  dynamic_include(self)
end
```